# My car only moves when it is plugged directly into both my pc and battery pack?

Tags: motor, battery, arduino-motor-shield

i built a car that works with four motors,one motor driver(specifically the l293d),the arduino and the battery pack with four AA-Batteries. The motors work fine though, but they only work when it is connected to the laptop and the battery pack.I've also removed the METAL insulation from the copper wire and now it is copper.Sadly i have also connected the two poles together and there was some lightning but no fire thankfully(by accident of course).if anyone else had the same issues and fixed them please contact me.
Thank you very much stranger.

Comment: If we imagine how you have all this wired together we will be solving imaginary problems.  I'm not sure what you mean by metal insulation.  Shielding? Metal armored cable?

Comment: the battery pack came with two copper wires one red and black and then there was some metal at the tip so i removed it to make it longer and now it doesn't work

Comment: look the problem is that it only works when it is plugged in both the laptop through the usb and the battery pack with four aa batteries

Comment: how do you make something longer by removing part of it?

Comment: look the copper wire had a metal tip and then i removed it and removed some insulation and now there is only copper out .

Comment: please have one of your friends read your post ... then ask them if they understand what you are describing

Comment: so, you have a piece of wire with a stripped end ... how is that a problem?

Comment: there is battery holder with two wires out positive and negative. And then i removed the metal tip that was transferring electricity onto the motor driver and along it some insulation to make the wire bigger.And now it only runs when it is connected to both the laptop and the battery holder.by it i mean the car

Comment: i don't know if this is the problem. i thought this was the problem.I have also disconnected the power while it was working

Comment: maybe you did not reconnect the wire properly or you broke something ... you did not describe anything clearly ... it is difficult to understand what you did if you use terms that make no sense, like `make the wire bigger`

Comment: Given that at least two of us don't understand your descriptions, it makes even more sense than usual that you include in-focus pictures of what you're talking about.

Comment: the orange arduino led is flashing and making a weird sound

Comment: ok i will try to put a picture

Comment: The best thing you can do is post a schematic, not a frizzy thing along with a picture of the parts that you modified and links to all of the other parts. You state: "orange arduino led is flashing and making a weird sound" How does a LED make a sound, they are not designed to. The best thing you can do for yourself is read the Arduino cookbook and do some online tutorials on basic electronics and the arduino.